# Formatted string parsing with conflicting delimiter

Tags: php, string, parsing, split

Whats the quickest/easiest way to parse a string delimited by `\` and with known keywords?

```
$str = 'key1\0815\key2\some string here\key3\string with \ in between\key4\0
```

I need to have them in an array (key => value) for later use, but how do I manage to split the string when some values might contain a `\`?
The keywords are known, but they are all unique.

explode() would fail on that and sscanf() would be a hughe amount of manual editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) to achieve this:

```
$arr = preg_split('/\\\\(?!\s)/', $str);

$result = array();

foreach (array_chunk($arr, 2) as $sub) {
    list($key, $value) = $sub;
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [keyword1] => 0815
    [keyword2] => some string here
    [keyword3] => string with \ in between
    [keyword4] => 0
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/137642)

Comment: What if there is no space after the \?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$result = array_combine(
    $keys = preg_grep('/key[\d]+/',
        $parts = preg_split('/(?:\\\\)?(key[\d]+)\\\\/', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)),
    $vals = array_diff($parts, $keys));
```

Comment: The lone `\d` does not need to be in a character class to work properly.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.  I'm not sure that we can rely on the sample keys in the question as realistic.  This answer _might_ be interpreting the question too literally.